# How to correctly ensure I'm not accessing elements out of a matrix?

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix

I'm having problems taking care of forbidden memory access. I have a task to find the highest mountain of a matrix (defined as a number that is higher than the sum of square of numbers surrounding it). Code works when I hard-code it not to access elements out of a matrix, which is not a good thing at all.

How do I make sure I never try to access memory that I'm not supposed to?

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<double>> Matrix;
typedef std::vector<double> Vector;
unsigned CalculateSum(Matrix mat, int counter, int x, int y)
{
unsigned sum(0);
if (x < counter) return 0;
for (int i(x - counter); i <= (x + counter); i++) {
    if(y < counter) return 0;
    for (int j(y - counter); j <= (y + counter); j++) {
        if (i == x && j == y) continue;
        sum += mat.at(i).at(j);
    }
}
return sum;
}
Matrix HighestMountain(Matrix mat) 
{
for (int i(0); i < mat.size(); i++) {
    if (mat.at(i).size() != mat.size()) throw std::domain_error("Wrong 
format");
}
Matrix insert;
Vector v;
int sum1(0), sum2(0);
int counter(1);
for (int i(0); i < mat.size(); i++) {
    for (int j(0); j < mat.at(i).size(); j++) {
        if(i == 0 || j == 0 || i == mat.size()-1 || j == mat.at(i).size()-1) continue;
        while (CalculateSum(mat, counter, i, j) < mat.at(i).at(j)) {
            insert.clear();
            for (int k(i - counter); k <= counter + 2; k++) {
                for (int l(j - counter); l <= counter + 2; l++) {
                    v.push_back(mat.at(k).at(l));
                }
                insert.push_back(v);
                v.clear();
            }
            counter++;
            if(counter > i || counter > j || i+counter > mat.size()-1 || 
            j+counter > mat.at(i).size()-1) break;
        }
    }
}
return insert;
}
```

Comment: You "make sure I never try to access memory that I'm not supposed to" by correctly implementing bounds checking. It's the same way you would generally use to get to Carnegie Hall: practice.

Comment: I do get that, but I've spent too much time trying to figure out what those boundaries should be. Tried skipping all elements that are on index[0][0] and also on index[max][max], but so far, I haven't been lucky.

Comment: C++ is hard. There is no "easy" button for C++. Learn safe programming practices. It's logically impossible to go out of bounds when all you have a beginning and an ending iterator, etched in stone, and all element access is based on them; compared to some completely unbound and uninitialized array index, that you have no idea where it came from.

Comment: Not allowed to use iterators, school assignment, haven't even got the point of learning about them. I'm still a beginner that just came from C to C++. I will keep trying to fix this though, but a little help most certainly wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Technically, `std::vector::at` that you use answers your title question: it throws an exception whenever you try to access memory out of bounds. Only thing I could suggest is to add helper access function which catches `std::out_of_range` and rethrows it with `x` and `y` to debug problems easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Start by identifying the various situations you have td deal with. Corner elements have three neighbors. Edge elements that aren’t corners have five. Interior elements have eight. So there are three distinct cases that you need code for.

Or you can use a matrix with each dimension 2 larger than your data and put zeros in all the edge elements. Then everything you’ve interested in is an interior element, with eight neighbors.

It’s all about design.

Comment: Okay, I've added some restrictions, such as if the number we're checking is on the edges, skip it, if the counter is bigger than the index of the number we're checking or if the number is on the edge, break the loop. For some reason I'm still getting simple "crash" error in the line `sum += mat.at(i).at(j)` line, and an `out_of_range` exception. What am I doing wrong?